# NodeWebkit (nw.js) allow self signed SSL certificate inside iframe

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I have a nw.js app with this package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "test_app",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "position": "center",
    "min_width": 800,
    "min_height": 500,
    "as_desktop": true,
    "resizable": true,
    "frame": true,
    "chromium-args": "--ignore-certificate-errors"
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true,
    "page-cache": true
  }
}
```

My index.html includes this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myfunc(){
        alert("my func");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem:

My site (src of iframe) https://www.example.com have a self signed certificate, so if I try to load in console give me this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Why `--ignore-certificate-errors` don't extended inside iframe child?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in one of the issues on [nw.js github repo](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3123#issuecomment-96393512).

Basically you need to use:

```
  "chromium-args": "--allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors",
```

And it has to go outside of the window object (e.g. after `name` property) in the `package.json` file.